# Getting all from json api array using php

Tags: php, json

I wanna improve on how to fetch data from an API. In this case I want to fetch every app-id from the Steam API, and list them one per line in a .txt file. Do I need an infinite (or a very high-number) loop (with `++` after every iteration) to fetch everyone? I mean, counting up from id 0 with for example a `foreach`-loop? I'm thinking it will take ages and sounds very much like bad practice.

How do I get every appid `{"appid:" n}` from the response of http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001?

```
<?php
    //API-URL
    $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001";
    //Fetch content and decode
    $game_json = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url), true);

    //Define file
    $file = 'steam.txt';
    //This is where I'm lost. One massive array {"app": []} with lots of {"appid": n}. 
    //I know how to get one specific targeted line, but how do I get them all?
    $line = $game_json['applist']['apps']['app']['appid'][every single line, one at a time]
    //Write to file, one id per line.
    //Like:
    //5
    //7
    //8
    //and so on
    file_put_contents($file, $line, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Any pointing just in the right direction will be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The pathetic attempt alone hopefully implies that I'm very sorry about not having made a very good attempt. Because I am.

Comment: You don't _need_ any counter at all with a foreach loop.

Comment: The json is very simple. Just extract the list !  $line = $game_json['applist']['apps']['app']. That s it !

Comment: How would it "improve" anything to put this is a `.txt` file?

Comment: @rjdown Always used counters before, it was the one thing I could imagine. Then for website urls ending in e.g. `/article/29312`, then counting every article up from 0 till I got what I want. 
@cpugourou Really? That's it? I'ma give it a go.

Comment: @PHPglue Not for any real-world use. I'm just imagining I might need to one day, for no reason at all. The question was meant to be more general like "What if I don't have a target?". The .txt file is just a "This is your results, did it work?" Might sound stupid, I know. The mind of a beginner is hard to imagine sometimes heh. Anything's an "improvement" to me really.

Comment: `$line = $game_json['applist']['apps']['app'];`. Might as well change `$line` to `$array`, if you want.

Comment: @PHPglue *"Notice: Array to string conversion in.."* I got "Array" for each appid instead of the id itself. Can't simply treat an array as a string, right? Gotta read up on this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about counters with `foreach` loops, they are designed to go through and work with *each* item in the object.

```
$file      = "steam.txt";
$game_list = "";
$url       = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001";
$game_json = file_get_contents($url);
$games     = json_decode($game_json);

foreach($games->applist->apps->app as $game) {
    // now $game is a single entry, e.g. {"appid":5,"name":"Dedicated server"}
    $game_list .= "$game->appid\n";
}

file_put_contents($file, $game_list);
```

Now you have a text file with 28000 numbers in it. Congratulations?